# Koin DI Android Unit testing ViewModel

Tags: android, unit-testing, koin

I use Koin DI in my app, and everything works fine. I have injected viewModels without no issue.

Eg, I have a calcViewModel with function:

```
class CalcViewModel(): ViewModel() {
    fun calculateNumber(): Int{
        var a = 5 + 3
        return a
    }
}
```

And in the app I use it like this:

```
class Application : Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
        // androidContext(this@MyApp)
        androidLogger(Level.DEBUG)
        androidContext(this@Application)
        modules(
            listOf(
                myModule
            )
        )
    }
```

And in my appModule file:

```
val myModule= module {
    viewModel { CalcViewModel() }
}
```

And in the app, whenever I need my viewModel instance, I just use:

```
private val calcViewModel by viewModel<CalcViewModel>()
```

And as I said, everything works perfectly but when I try to write a simple unit test for this function

```
fun calculateNumber(): Int{
        var a = 5 + 3
        return a
}
```

from the view model I have null pointer.

This is the test Class I tried

```
class CalcViewModelTest: KoinTest{

val calcViewModel:CalcViewModel by inject()

@Before
fun setup() {

    startKoin {
        module { single { myModule} }
      
    }
}

@Test
fun calculateNumber(){
    val result = calcViewModel.calculateNumber()  // here I get that error when trying to access calcViewModel var
    Assert.assertEquals(result,8)
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    stopKoin()
}

}
```

And everytime I get this error when I try to run my unit test:

```
org.koin.core.error.NoBeanDefFoundException: No definition found for 
class:'com.package.CalcViewModel'. Check your definitions!
```

Also if I use the same way to fetch the viewModel in test class like in the app:

```
val calcViewModel by viewModel<CalcViewModel>()
```

It uses a different constructor that asks for 3 params (class, owner, scope)

I also imported in the gradle:

```
testImplementation "org.koin:koin-androidx-viewmodel:$koin_version"
testImplementation "org.koin:koin-test:$koin_version"
```

Did anyone tried to write unit tests with Koin and using viewModels ?

Thanks

Comment: it should be modules not module

Comment: @Blackbelt It is just another way of loading modules, if you use module like I did you can add one module, if use modules it expects list of modules. I tried with list of modules too, no luck. In the app works great but I cannot unit test it.

Comment: the documentations says to use `modules` not `module` with `startKoin`.  `module` seems to be to declare (create) a module, but I don't have much experience with koin

Comment: @Blackbelt I just tried like that too just to be 1000% sure, startKoin { modules ( listOf(  myModule) )} and the same error as before.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the end I just initialized the viewModel and used the instance.

```
 private lateinit var viewModel: CalcViewModel
```

and later in setUp()

```
viewModel = CalcViewModel()
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Koin Documentation](https://insert-koin.io/docs/quickstart/junit-test/), you need to use `by inject()` to create instance of class.

```
    val calcViewModel by inject<CalcViewModel>()
```

Then, create `koinTestRule` like this.

```
    @get:Rule
    val koinTestRule = KoinTestRule.create {
        printLogger()
        modules(myModule)
    }
```